# Page not found (404) on django router

Tags: django

I have the below router

```
router.register(r'get-customers/<int:number>', GetCustomersViewSet, basename='get-customers')
```

when i visit

```
http://127.0.0.1:9090/get-customers/20
```

I am getting the above error i am not sure what can be the problem.
But when i change the router to

```
router.register(r'get-customers', GetCustomersViewSet, basename='get-customers')
```

and visit

```
http://127.0.0.1:9090/get-customers
```

It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add

```
router.register(r'get-customers/(?P<page>\d+)', GetCustomersViewSet, basename='get-customers')
```